# How to use offline.js or online.js with a submit button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, github

While these (Offline or Online.js) keep constantly checking for internet connection by setting timeout, What I want them to do is to check network connection only when the user presses the SUBMIT button. I don't want any timeout that make them check for connection continuously.

Honestly, I have been checking out all the websites and stack overflow questions for weeks, but nothing could satisfy me and my last resort was to go with these js libraries. I'm kinda new to js so a little help would be much appreciated!

Right now, my code using Online.js looks like this

```
<script src="online.js"></script>

          $("#submit2").click(function()
             {
              if(window.onLine === true)
                 {           
                 console.log("You're ONLINE");
                 }
             else
                 { 
                  console.log("You're OFFLINE");
                 }
              });
```

The online.js link for your reference:
https://github.com/PixelsCommander/OnlineJS

Comment: If you have access to your server, you could using `$.ajax` JQuery method to check if you can access to your server, so if you have internet access.

Comment: @Zeratops I am running a tomcat server in my system and I used $.ajax as you said. But the problem is, when I stop the server and submit it immediately, it tells me I'm online though it has to show "I'm Offline". How to solve this issue? Please reply!

Answer (score 0):

[Edit: my original answer was regarding a [different JS library](http://github.hubspot.com/offline/): . Took a while to realise you were talking about a different one. But this one probably is similar to what you are looking for. So you might as well take a look at this.]

I havnt used this js but the properties section in the documentation mentions functions for this purpose (at least that is what it seems to me):
http://github.hubspot.com/offline/#properties

So maybe you can do Offline.check() inside the .click of your button.

Also i think interceptRequests to false will instruct it to stop monitoring ajax requests for the connectivity status.its mentioned here: http://github.hubspot.com/offline/#advanced

hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I tried with offline.js already. It returns true always, even if my connection is down.   if(Offline.check()) returns true always.